# Extract phrase count from text files based on a keyword

Tags: python, nlp, keyword

I have a set of text files with blurbs of text and I need to search these for a particular keyword such that a set of words before and/or after the keyword (i.e. `phrases`) are returned along with a count of the phrases across the files. For example, contents of a few of files are:

File 1: `This is a great day. I wish I could go to a beautiful green park today but unfortunately, we are in a lockdown!`

File 2: `Having a beautiful green park close to your house is great.`

File 3: `I visited a green park today. My friend also visited a green park today.`

So if I search for the keyword `park`, I'm looking for the output to be a set of phrases (let's say one word before & after `park`), ranked based on how many times the phrase occurs across files. So in this example, the output should be:

`green park today: 2`

`green park close: 1`

Is there a way I can achieve this in `Python`, maybe using some `NLP` libraries or even without them. I have some code in my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70207268/python-return-phrases-from-text-based-on-keyword) but that doesn't solve the purpose (I'll perhaps delete that post once I get a response to this one).

Thank you

Comment: Look up Apriori model, it could help you out.

Comment: The tool you are looking for is usually called "concordance search".

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected output above, it looks like you only want to add one to the count for a single phrase per file (even if it appears several times in the same file). Below is an example of how you can do this without any special NLP libraries, just defining "words" as chains of non-space characters delimited by spaces (I'm assuming you know how to read text from a file so leaving that part out).

```
from collections import Counter

str1 = "This is a great day. I wish I could go to a beautiful green park today but unfortunately, we are in a lockdown!"
str2 = "Having a beautiful green park close to your house is great."
str3 = "I visited a green park today. My friend also visited a green park today."

str1_words = ["START"] + str1.split(" ") + ["END"]
str2_words = ["START"] + str2.split(" ") + ["END"]
str3_words = ["START"] + str3.split(" ") + ["END"]

print(str1_words)

all_phrases = []
SEARCH_WORD = "park"

for words in [str1_words, str2_words, str3_words]:
    phrases = []
    for i in range(1, len(words) - 1):
        if words[i] == SEARCH_WORD:
            phrases.append(" ".join(words[i-1:i+2]))
    # Only count each phrase once for this text
    phrases = set(phrases)
    all_phrases.extend(phrases)

phrase_count = Counter(all_phrases)
print(phrase_count.most_common())
```

The output is:

```
[('green park today', 1), ('green park close', 1), ('green park today.', 1)]
```

This perfectly demonstrates the problem with the definition of a "word" above - punctuation is treated as part of the word. For a better way to do it, look into the **NLTK** library, specifically methods for "word tokenization".

Hopefully the above gives you an idea of how to get started on this.

Comment: thank you, this is a great starting point! Please could you advise if there is a way while picking the phrase in `phrases.append(" ".join(words[i-1:i+2]))` by which I could increase the word limit if there is a 'noise' word e.g. conjunction/preposition? Example, for `str3` if I search keyword `green` then the output is `visited a green park` instead of just `a green park`. I can list the noise words in a separate text file and reference in the script.

Comment: Yep, you could use a while loop with a counter variable to increase the counter until you encounter a non-"noise" word in either direction then substitute those counter variables into the line `phrases.append(" ".join(words[i-1:i+2]))`.

By the way, i think what you are referring to are usually known as "stopwords" or "function words". This tutorial would give you everything you need to do NLP-wise for your use case: https://pythonspot.com/nltk-stop-words/

Comment: Thank you I'll try this out!

Comment: I tried out the below per your suggestion, but the only issue with this is that it only checks if the next word is a `stopword` or not. So, if I want my phrase to pick 2 or more non `stopwords` next to the `keyword`, & the next word isn't a `stopword` but the next-to-next word is, then it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks `if word.lower() == SEARCH_WORD.lower():
 
 cnt_left = index
 cnt_right = index
 while a[cnt_left-1].lower() in stopwords:
  cnt_left -= 1
 while a[cnt_right+1].lower() in stopwords:
  cnt_right += 1

 phrases.append(" ".join(a[cnt_left-1:cnt_right+3]).strip())`